# Cast Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer to Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer

Tags: c#, azure-webjobs

We are trying to hack WebJobs to connect to storage as an MSI user to comply with some requirements.  we are using this technique

https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/2109

the problem is this line

```
webJobConfiguration.Services.AddSingleton(new DistributedLockManagerContainerProvider
{
     InternalContainer = container
});
```

Apparently the Azure Webjob api hasn't been updated to use `Microsoft.Azure` and this is still using a container type of `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlobContainer`.  Wouldn't be a problem except that our entire API has been converted to `Microsoft.Azure` namespace classes.

Is there an easy way to switch between the old and new namespaces?

Comment: Could you please provide your code?